# Unable to get the file from web using workbook.open

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import a CSV file from the website to my worksheet.
My local excel has other connections to websites that fetch the data using a power query.

Below is the code I am having issues with. I am not able to navigate to the CSV file the second time.
ie.. only If I close and open my local excel then only workbook.open() is working fine.

Error I am getting is: sorry we cannot open "" because server is not responding. (actually I can navigate to the csv file.. no issues with server).

Also, I can see some files with name centraltable.laccdb is getting created at C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache when I use workbook.open. If I close my local excel the laccb file is getting deleted.

Please help on how I can run the code second time, as I am triggering my macro every 10min.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
URLOI = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/nsccl/fao_participant_oi_" & dt & ".csv"
On Error Resume Next
DoEvents
Set oWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=URLOI)
 If Not oWB Is Nothing Then
        Instructions.Range("A" & k) = Format(Now - 11, "dd-mmm-yy")
            If Not IsError(Application.Match("FII", oWB.Sheets(1).Columns("A").Cells, 0)) Then
                    Var = Application.Match("FII", oWB.Sheets(1).Columns("A").Cells, 0)
                    Instructions.Range("B" & k) = oWB.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Var).Value
             End If
    End If
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With 
        oWB.Close False
        Set oWB = Nothing
DoEvents
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question this should work for you. Need to add your references.

```
Sub CSVHelp()
    'DECLARE
        Dim URL As String
        Dim filePath As String
        Dim sheetName As String
    'DEFINE
        URL = "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/cities.csv"
        filePath = "C:\Desktop\myCSVfile.csv"
        sheetName = "Sheet1"
    
    'DELETE
        Worksheets(sheetName).Activate
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    'Get Data
        Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        objHTTP.send ("")
        replyTXT = objHTTP.responseText
    'Store in File
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(filePath, True)
        a.WriteLine (replyTXT)
        a.Close
    'Import to Sheet
        i = 0
        Dim fso As FileSystemObject: Set fso = New FileSystemObject
        Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading, False)
        
        Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
            Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = txtStream.ReadLine
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        txtStream.Close
        
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: we can directly use workbook.open to access the file instead of "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP"..

Comment: Did you try replacing some of the lines with "workbook.open"? Were you able to get it working to your needs?